# FB.api post uses get

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post a comment to a stream post using the js sdk. My code is this:

`FB.api(linkPage, 'post', {message: comment}, function(res){});`

Where linkpage is a correct url to a stream post using the graph api, and comment is a valid string. When this code runs however, the network pane of Chrome shows that the 'post' param does not make the sdk perform a http post, but instead appends the querystring parameter "method=post". The request method is still GET, the api responds with a valid looking commentid, however the comment is never visible on the stream post. Using the graph api explorer to POST to exactly the same api entry point that linkPage is set to with the same comment works perfectly.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

For me `FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message:'Hello'}, callback);` creates a status update which is visible only on my page. It's not visible on a news feed page.

It's not a bug that a `FB.api` call sends a `GET` request instead of a `POST` one.

It's because of browser security.